# Styling the placeholder in a TextField

Tags: html, css, material-ui, jss

The [TextField](https://material-ui-next.com/api/text-field/) API doesn't mention anything about how one could style the pseudo placeholder element of the input element.

Basically, I would like to change the default styling of the placeholder text, and [the normal bag of tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/p/placeholder/) doesn't work, as I cannot access the element.

Is there a way I can get to it? And if so, what is the JSS/React/DOM equivalent way of writing `::-webkit-input-placeholder`?

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/p/placeholder/

Comment: Why can you not access the element? Even if the element is generated dynamically, your CSS styles that target it will still apply.

Comment: @CasperSL That's just being lazy. That link was already part of my question.

Comment: @ObsidianAge That means I would have to write my CSS outside of the JS, wouldn't it? And further, it would also probably be tightly linked to the inner internals of the component, right?

Answer (score 61):

**Case 1**

Put the desired placeholder text in the `label` property of the `TextField` component, and use the `labelClassName` property of the `TextField` to customize it. You could also pass `InputLabelProps` with a `className`, `classes` or `style` attribute.

**Case 2**

Refrain from using the `label` property of `TextField` and put the placeholder text on its `placeholder` property instead. Leverage `InputProps` to override the generated HTML `input` element's class.

**Code**

The code below covers both aforementioned cases. [CodeSandbox snippet](https://codesandbox.io/s/73667wp9j6?module=%2Fpages%2Findex.js).

```
import React from 'react';
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';
import { withStyles } from 'material-ui/styles';
import withRoot from '../components/withRoot';

const styles = {
  'input-label': {
    textOverflow: 'ellipsis',
    whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
    overflow: 'hidden',
    width: '100%',
    color: 'red'
  },

  'input': {
    '&::placeholder': {
      textOverflow: 'ellipsis !important',
      color: 'blue'
    }
  }
};

class Index extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div style={ {width: 150, margin: '0 auto'} }>
      {/* Uses "label" and "labelClassName". */}
      <TextField
        fullWidth
        label='I am a really really long red TextField label'
        labelClassName={ this.props.classes['input-label'] } />

      {/* Uses "label" and "InputLabelProps" with inline styles. */}
      <TextField
        fullWidth
        label='I am a really really long green TextField label'
        InputLabelProps={{
          style: {
            textOverflow: 'ellipsis',
            whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
            overflow: 'hidden',
            width: '100%',
            color: 'green'
          } }} />

      {/* Uses "placeholder" and "InputProps" with "classes". */}
      <TextField
        fullWidth
        margin='normal'
        placeholder='I am a really really long glue TextField label'
        InputProps={{ classes: {input: this.props.classes['input']} }} />
    </div>;
  }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(Index);
```

**EDIT**

The previous solutions are good if you'd like to personalize a specific component instance. To change the placeholder globally, see [ninjaPixel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57995968/2619107).

Answer (score 22):

You can style the input at the top-level of your app, which will save you from having to create a custom input component with your styles applied to it (as suggested in other answers).

```
import { ThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/styles";
import { createMuiTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const customTheme = createMuiTheme({
overrides: {
  MuiInput: {
    input: {
      "&::placeholder": {
        color: "gray"
      },
      color: "white", // if you also want to change the color of the input, this is the prop you'd use
    }
  }
});

// Render it like this
<ThemeProvider theme={customTheme}>
  <App />
</ThemeProvider>
```

Comment: It didn't work for me. Instead styling MuiInput you would add:
`MuiFormLabel: { root: { color: 'grey' }},`

Comment: Also I'd like to point out something this answer fails to mention and would spare me some time if I knew about it before: you have to pay attention to the variant of your TextField. E.g. if it `variant='filled'` you have to use `MuiFilledInput` instead of `MuiInput`.
Apart from that this answer is great and exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 19):

You can use the following code to apply the placeholder style.

```
const styles = (theme: any) => createStyles({
input: {
    '&::placeholder': {
      fontStyle: 'italic',
    },
  },
});

<TextField
  margin="normal"
  variant="outlined"
  placeholder="Filter..."
  InputProps={{
    classes: { input: classes.input}
  }}
/>
```

Answer (score 14):

Use InputLabelProps on TextField

```
<TextField
   InputLabelProps={{
      style: { color: '#fff', some other Styles }, 
   }}
/>
```

Comment: I tried the other solutions to change the placeholder color and they didn't work, this works for me

Comment: After trying so many solutions, this alone worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I haven't found a proper answer to how I can access the inner input element, but as to how one could target the placeholder element using JSS, I found the answer [in the source](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v1-beta/src/Input/Input.js#L157) of the `Input` element, of which `TextField` is composed.

Basically, it's using the straight css names, just enclosed in quotes:
`'&::-webkit-input-placeholder': { color: 'blue' }`

Answer (score 4):

you can add styling to your input using `::placeholder` selector in `css` it'll work

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
  color: pink;
}
::-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 19+ */
  color: pink;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* IE 10+ */
  color: pink;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
  color: pink;
}
```

Comment: I wasn't asking generally. The question is tagged material-ui, so it's specifically using JavaScript and JSS. I added a JSS tag now to further emphasize it, but it should be pretty clear from my last paragraph.

Comment: above css selector is global property for placeholder color change u  can use it for material-ui also

Comment: I don't want to change it globally, that's sloppy. otherwise I wouldn't be asking this specific question. I already knew the proper CSS props, as is apparent from the question. It's targetting the specific pseudo element contained inside a TextField that is hard.

Answer (score 4):

To style only the placeholder without the label on top when focused - do the following:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    label: {
         color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26)'
    }
}));

const LoginForm = () => {
    const classes = useStyles();

    return (
         <TextField
              ...
              InputLabelProps={{
                   classes: {
                       root: classes.label,
                   }
              }}
         />
    )
}
```

Comment: What is this an answer to?

Comment: This is my way to style a placeholder in a TextField

Answer (score 3):

Nothing worked for me except this solution (with MUI 5 and sx-props instead of makestyles etc) :

```js
import React, { FC } from 'react';
import { TextField } from '@mui/material';

const searchStyle = {
  // some other styles
};


const searchField: FC < Props > = () => {
 return ( 
 < TextField 
    sx = {
      searchStyle
    }
    placeholder = {
      "Search"
    }
    inputProps = {
      {
        sx: {
          '&::placeholder': {
            color: 'red',
            opacity: 1, // otherwise firefox shows a lighter color
          },
        },
      }
    }
  />
  );
};
```

(From https://stackoverflow.com/a/70626286/3134778)

Answer (score 2):

Whether you are using the outlined, filled, or standard variants, the placeholder you might be referring to is actually the label and not the ::placeholder.
You can use `sx` in newest MUI versions.

```html
<TextField
    label="Username"
    variant="standard"
    sx={{ input: { color: "yellow" }, "label": {color: "blue"} }} 
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<TextField
        placeholder='Search...'
        inputProps={{
            style: {color: 'white'}
        }}
/>
```

Answer (score -4):

With styled components I just use:

```
const StyledTextField = styled(TextField)`
    label {
        font-style: italic;
    }
`;
```

Comment: Hi, Eric. That answer is not related to the question. I suggest deleting it to avoid downvotes.