# React placeholderTextColor does not work on my TextField

Tags: reactjs

placeholderTextColor does not work on my TextField

My code is here: https://codesandbox.io/s/74k5n65x1x?fontsize=14

I expected placeholderTextColor to change the color of the placeholder text, however the color of the placeholder text remains unchanged.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Styling the placeholder in a TextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47804380/styling-the-placeholder-in-a-textfield)

Comment: None of the solutions at that link worked for me. However it seems like the answer is - you can't really do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it will be better if you post the code here.

anyway `TextField` doesn't have property called `placeholderTextColor` , instead you can add class to your text field

```
<TextField
    className="some-class"
    placeholder="Enter a message, hit return..."
/>
```

and in your css file

```
.some-class input::placeholder {
  color: blue !important;
}
```

don't forget to import your css file

Comment: did you import your css file ?

Comment: Thank you - you are very great genius.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/), there is no `placeholderTextColor` for the `TextField` component.