# style the css of the placeholder

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, material-ui

- I am trying to style the css of the placeholder.
- so I gave color red inside the input class
- but still its not changing.
- I researched and found this link  [Styling the placeholder in a TextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47804380/styling-the-placeholder-in-a-textfield)
- but still no luck
- can you tell me how to fix it.
- providing my code snippet and sandbox below.

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-iw4gr

```or-tag-here
input: {
    marginLeft: 8,
    flex: 1,
    "&::placeholder": {
      // fontSize: '14 !important',
      color: "red"
    }
  },

  <InputBase
          className={classes.input}
          placeholder="Search Google Maps"
          inputProps={{ "aria-label": "Search Google Maps" }}
        />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/* try this */
/* Attention: There is a space between & and ::-webkit-input-placeholder */

input: {
    marginLeft: 8,
    flex: 1,
    "& ::-webkit-input-placeholder": {
      color: "red !important"
    }
  }
```

Besides, set input placeholder like this

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit browsers */
  color: "red"
}

::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
  color: "red"
}

:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
 color: "red"
}
```

Comment: This won't work.. This turns the entire field red, including the text the user types in

Comment: I revised the answer and Please try again. Is it what you want? Attention: There is a space between & and ::-webkit-input-placeholder

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the `className` properties, you should use the `classes` properties instead to overwrite the default stylings for the InputBase component.

I think the reason why `className` does not work in this scenario, is because `className` only targets the stylings of the wrapper element, whereas `classes` will allow you to fully overwrite the specific elements of `InputBase`, such as the `input` itself. You may read up more about it on the documentation over [here](https://material-ui.com/api/input-base/#css).

```
<InputBase
  classes={{
    input: classes.input,
  }}
  placeholder="Search Google Maps"
/>
```

I have replicated a demo for you over [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/placeholder-styling-und6w).

Answer (score 0):

What I believe you want is the pseudo-selector `::placeholder { color: red; }`

[CanIUse.com](https://caniuse.com/#search=%3A%3Aplaceholder) shows this is having fairly widespread acceptance.

This will allow the placeholder to be red but the input to be formatted in whatever color you have specified.