# How to show both label and placeholder in material-ui TextField

Tags: material-ui

In Material-UI (MUI) TextField, we can have both a label and a placeholder, but when the text field is empty, we can only see the label. We have to start editing the TextField in order to see the placeholder. Is there a way to say that both the label and placeholder should show initially when the field is empty? We'd also like to style the placeholder slightly differently by making it slightly gray compared to the black label text color. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

you can force input label to shrink. https://mui.com/components/text-fields/#shrink

you can add input Text color with `sx` props on TextField. placeholder takes color from the input text color too. you can test this by removing `inputProps` props in below code.

if you want different colors for input text and placeholder use `inputProps`
ref: [Styling the placeholder in a TextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47804380/styling-the-placeholder-in-a-textfield)

```
<TextField
  sx={{
    "& .MuiOutlinedInput-root": {
      color: "red"
    }
  }}
  variant="outlined"
  label="Your custom label"
  placeholder="Placeholder Text"
  InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
  inputProps={{
    sx: {
      "&::placeholder": {
        color: "green"
      }
    }
  }}
/>
```

Answer (score 5):

iam still looking the best resolution..

my current approach

```
<TextField focused label="Standard" placeholder='lorem ipsum' />
```

or

```
 <TextField  InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }} label="Standard" placeholder='lorem ipsum' />
```

Answer (score 4):

This works for me:

```
<TextField  InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }} label="Name" placeholder='lorem ipsum' />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use placeholder and label both.  but, when the user click on the textfield, the placeholder will be displayed

```
<TextField id="standard-basic" placeholder="enter" label="Standard" variant="standard" />
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/basictextfields-material-demo-forked-i7tcn?file=/demo.js

Comment: Yes, in addition to seeing the label  before the user edits the field, we would like to show the placeholder before the user clicks on the field (similar to how a placeholder works for a regular input). This allows the user to see the help information in the placeholder before they interact with the text field.

Answer (score 0):

In actually it is not a placeholder in textfield. It is label.
It changes with simple classname of textfield "MUI form label root".
Assign colour on normal way.