# MUI, onFocus of TextInput

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I would like the defaultValue of a TextField to show "Username" upon page render. onFocus, I would like "Username" to disappear so that the user may comfortably type. I tried the following:

```
function Login() {
  const [usernameDefaultValue, setUsernameDefaultValue] = useState("Username");

  return (    <div>
        <TextField
          required
          id="standard-required"
          label="Required"
          defaultValue={usernameDefaultValue}
          onFocus={() => setUsernameDefaultValue('')}
          variant="standard"
        />

)}
```

but as it is currently the user must double-click the defaultValue ("Username") in order to clear the field for their actual username.

Comment: Just a curiosity. Why don't you set usernameDefaultValue to "" or undefined and use a placeholder with the value "Username" such as <Textfield placeholder="Username" ...>?

Comment: I tried that, but if I use "placeholder" it shifts (or omits, i can't remember which) the "required" field

Comment: You can try this for the label/placeholder issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70624192/how-to-show-both-label-and-placeholder-in-material-ui-textfield/70626286

Answer (score 0):

No need for temporary values to be controlled by `state` when using this library. This is what the `label` prop is there for. Set the label to "Username" and set the state separately, with an initial value of `''`

```
function Login() {
  const [userName, setUserName] = useState('')

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const name = e.target.value

    return setUserName(name)
  }

  return (
    <TextField
       id="standard-required"
       label="Username"
       onChange={handleChange}
       required 
       value={userName}
       variant="standard"
    />
  )
}
```